# no module name pyinotify in mitmf

Tags: python, module, pyinotify

hello i have a problem in installing mitmf in kali-linux version 2020.1a
during installation i performed following task in shell

1. `apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools libpcap0.8-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev libssl-dev libjpeg-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcapstone3 libcapstone-dev libffi-dev file`
2. `git clone https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf`
3. `cd MITMf && git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

but in step 4 there is obstacle that's: `pip command not found`

so i try to install `pip` with command: `sudo apt install python-pip`

but it doesn't work and says : `Unable to locate package python-pip`

then i try to install `pip3` with command: `sudo apt install python3-pip`

and it get install and i complete the step 4 command of installing `mitmf` 
i.e : 4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

after that when i run help command for `mitmf` i.e., `python mitmf.py --help`

It display following things

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "mitmf.py", line 29, in <module>

    import core.responder.settings as settings

  File "/home/tester/MITMf/core/responder/settings.py", line 24, in <module>

    from core.configwatcher import ConfigWatcher

  File "/home/tester/MITMf/core/configwatcher.py", line 20, in <module>

    import pyinotify

ImportError: No module named pyinotify
```

I have also try with this command : `python3 mitmf.py`

then following result popup

```sh
File "mitmf.py", line 38
    print get_banner()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so please help me to solve problem with no module name pynotify. what to do to solve this problems.
I get stuck here and unable to solve this problem .

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow. Use formatting to make the question readable.

Answer (score 1):

MITMF installation 2021|sep
youtube link | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDnQOIQj3zI

```
apt-get install python-dev-is-python2 python-setuptools libpcap0.8-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev libssl-dev libjpeg-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcapstone4 libcapstone-dev
```

---

```
apt install pip
```

---

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

---

```
which python3
```

---

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

---

```
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

---

```
mkvirtualenv MITMf -p /usr/bin/python2.7
```

---

```
git clone https://github.com/byt3bl33d3r/MITMf
```

---

```
cd MITMf && git submodule init && git submodule update --recursive
```

---

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

```
python mitmf.py --help
```

---

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have had the same issues you have been having and I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  You need to download packages before you install them.  It took me a WHILE to figure that out.
Try pip3 for the -r requirements it might work

I think you need to download get-pip.py first to download and install all the missing modules and to use the -r requirements
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
now you may be able to use the pip for -r requirements

Navigate to root directory or cd .. as far back as you can go
first cmd
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

2nd
python get-pip.py

Then I think you can start downloading and install all of the missing modules.
Whenever you start sudo ./mitmf.py or sudo python mitmf.py you will get an error that says for example no module named pyinotify
open 2 terminals
1st terminal
Navigate to root directory or cd .. as far back as you can go
2nd terminal
navigate to your MITMf directory
start mitmf to get the no module name
ex no module named pyinotify

1st terminal
sudo pip download pyinotify
sudo pip install pyinotify

2nd terminal
start mitmf with sudo ./mitmf.py or sudo python mitmf.py

if another no module error occurs repeat from the pip download and pip install steps
try to start mitmf again 
Repeat as many times as you need and try both mitmf cmds to see if it is corrected.
I had to download and install 8 modules before it actually worked.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First, do

```sh
sudo pip download pyinotify 
sudo pip install pyinotify
```

Then, start `mitmf` with `sudo ./mitmf.py or sudo python mitmf.py`

If another no module error occurs repeat from the pip download and pip install steps try to start mitmf again Repeat as many times as you need and try both mitmf cmds to see if it is corrected. I had to download and install 8 modules before it actually worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

so you would first download with sudo pip download pyinotify
then you need to install it with sudo pip install pyinotify
then in the other terminal start the mitmf to see if it works or gives another error
then repeat those steps again.  The module names are not always correct so you may have to search the correct names.  for example there was an error i got no module name magic.  When I did sudo pip download magic the download failed.  then i searched and found that the download cmd needs to be sudo pip download python-magic.  the pip download and install need it to be python-magic and not just magic.
these are the 8 modules I had to download and install
pyinotify
configobj
twisted
bs4
pefile
python-magic instead of magic
capstone
Pillow instead of PIL

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue recently. Since Kali 2020 a new user is always created in the installation process and we don't login as the root user anymore and it looks like it is causing issues with this. there was an interesting observation done when doing this if you don't use sudo while installing packages it gets installed in a different location compared to running it as sudo which is the reason the program is not able to access them and shows you the error for missing packages.

try running the installation as root i.e

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and run the program as root with

```
sudo ./mitmf.py or sudo python mitimf.py
```

if you see any more missing packages then don't forget to install them with sudo i.e

```
sudo pip install package-name
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Following commands:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

Then install requirements.txt using pip2:

```
pip2 install -r requirements.txt

python mitmf.py -h
```